# How to stop GNU Fortran Compiler to show debug info during runtime?

Tags: gcc, gfortran

The following lin is used to compile an executable from the Fortran source code

```
gfortran -funderscoring -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src/abc.o" "../src/abc.f"
```

When I run my program in command prompt and errors occur, it will show runtime errors in the command prompt (see the runtime error example below). I want to disable the display of the runtime errors as I am worried that this will reveal the source code. How can I do that?

```
At line 429 of file ../src/abc.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0xffffffff
#1  0xffffffff
#2  0xffffffff
#3  0xffffffff
#4  0xffffffff
#5  0xffffffff
#6  0xffffffff
#7  0xffffffff
#8  0xffffffff
#9  0xffffffff
#10  0xffffffff
#11  0xffffffff
#12  0xffffffff
#13  0xffffffff
```

Comment: Why would you distribute binaries full of runtime errors?

Comment: @Amiy the runtime error is due to the wrong input format, not the binary itself.

Comment: You are worried of this? It will be only of a minor aid to the person disassembling your program. The code has the references to the runtime library symbils anyway.

Comment: @KenT you should always validate user input and filter it. If any input causes a runtime errors then your program has run-time bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such option and I am not useful of its usefulness anyway. Fortran rewuires an error condition to be handled eventhough it does not prescribe the form of the message.

You can always use the `iostat=` or `err=` specifiers to handle the error conditions yourself in anu way you like.